# Is there anyway to find whether the add to home screen - app icon has been added to home screen using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, progressive-web-apps

Configured our app to support Add to home screen option, to ask for permission we added one button, onclick the prompt will ask to add the icon in home screen. If the user keep clicking close, then it wont ask further, so the button becomes non-functional.

If the user already added icon, i didn't get any method to find it.

Comment: Why do you need to know? How would it make any difference to your app?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, If the user added the app to home screen, it is most likely a regular user who likes your app. This is a valuable information if you are trying to sell some additional functionality to the user.

Comment: @JoseCherian -  Your subsequent follow up to sell some additional functionality to the user can anyway be done by capturing the user's action by result.outcome of beforeinstallprompt event (See my answer below). If he accepted, he likes your app already (as per your reasoning) :) . Anyway, after some more research, I could see that there is indeed an option to figure out if the app was successfully installed (See the update in my answer), and hence wether the app icon has been added to home screen.

Comment: @SaurabhRajpal,  Thanks for the answer and that is once way of doing it. But  if I need to write code to save it and later check it back, I could also log details about each fetch request from the user to indexeddb and predict much better time to prompt for an in-app purchase.

Comment: For sure. Once you have captured the event, you can always save it and later use it for any number of use cases which you desire to offer to the user. Basically the question was to capture the install event, which is answered now. Thanks for providing the context for the possible use cases around this requirement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any method best known to me to capture whether the app icon has been added to home screen or not. Simple reason for that could be absence of any valid existing use case. However, what you can capture is the action taken by the user. When the A2HS banner is shown, you can tap into the `beforeinstallprompt` event to determine the choice made by the user when presented with the banner.

The code below shows this in action:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(event) {
  event.userChoice.then(function(result) {                      

  if(result.outcome == 'dismissed') {                         
    // User dismissed
  }
  else {
    // User accepted
  }
});
});
```

**UPDATE:**

While going through the [official doc for A2HS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/), found a way to determine if the app was successfully added to the users home screen after they accepted the prompt, you can listen for the `appinstalled` event. Code:

```
window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
  app.logEvent('a2hs', 'installed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, By this we can track whether the app is installed, but after the installation, if the user opens the site _nth_ time, then how to find whether the app is already installed or not yet installed ?

Comment: You can save this in your app storage (say indexedDB) and later reference it any time you want to know whether the app was already installed. This can be just like another key value pair in the db- "installed":'true'.

Comment: @SaurabhRajpal and what if user uninstalls the app from his device and you want to manually display him the prompt again? I guess the `installed` value won't be cleared then.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no "uninstall" event available yet using which you can clear off that flag from storage through code. For displaying the prompt again, you can't do it manually. Browser should provide you the A2HS event first. Based on that you can follow the same flow again.

Comment: What is this `app.logEvent` method? And what is this `app` object?

Answer (score 0):

appinstalled does not work

```
window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
  app.logEvent('a2hs', 'installed');
});
```